# Accessing object storage bucket with a pre-authenticated request using oci java sdk

Tags: object-storage, pre-authentication, cloud-object-storage, oci-java-sdk

I have only preauthenticated URL,namespace and bucket name. Is there any way to upload and download data using key with help of oci java sdk. Is there a proper documentation for this, and If there is then which version of java and maven it supported and all the dependencies with it.

I was trying, firstly make a builder with endpoint(URL). Using builder make a objectStorageClient
but in argument it requires AuthenticationDetailsprovider. So I pass an empty object of AuthenticationDetailsprovider. But I am getting this error.

java.util.NoSuchElementException: No http provider available; add dependency on one of the oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-* choices, e.g. oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-jersey
at com.oracle.bmc.http.client.DefaultHolder.findHttpProvider(HttpProvider.java:48) ~[oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-3.12.1.jar:na]
at com.oracle.bmc.http.client.DefaultHolder.getDefault(HttpProvider.java:32) ~[oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-3.12.1.jar:na]
at com.oracle.bmc.http.client.HttpProvider.getDefault(HttpProvider.java:19) ~[oci-java-sdk-common-httpclient-3.12.1.jar:na]
at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.BaseClient.(BaseClient.java:79) ~[oci-java-sdk-common-3.12.1.jar:na]
at com.oracle.bmc.http.internal.BaseSyncClient.(BaseSyncClient.java:36) ~[oci-java-sdk-common-3.12.1.jar:na]
at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient.(ObjectStorageClient.java:45) ~[oci-java-sdk-objectstorage-generated-3.12.1.jar:na]
at com.oracle.bmc.objectstorage.ObjectStorageClient$Builder.build(ObjectStorageClient.java:139) ~[oci-java-sdk-objectstorage-generated-3.12.1.jar:na]
at com.scry.infrastructure.oci.OciUtil.getOracleOCIClient(OciUtil.java:76) ~[classes/:na]
at com.scry.infrastructure.oci.OciUtil.uploadFile(OciUtil.java:63) ~[classes/:na]
at com.scry.infrastructure.oci.OciUtil.uploadRootCaFile(OciUtil.java:44) ~[classes/:na]
at com.scry.service.CertificateService.uploadRootCaFile(CertificateService.java:112) ~[classes/:na]
at com.scry.service.CertificateService.uploadCertificateFile(CertificateService.java:92) ~[classes/:na]
at com.scry.controller.CertificateController.uploadCertificateFile(CertificateController.java:61) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_281]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doPost(FrameworkServlet.java:909) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:4.0.FR]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.21.jar:5.3.21]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1787) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) [tomcat-embed-core-9.0.64.jar:9.0.64]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [na:1.8.0_281]

Answer (score 0):

Please refer to [the documentation for how to create PARs using the Java SDK](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/api/#/en/objectstorage/20160918/PreauthenticatedRequest/CreatePreauthenticatedRequest).

I believe you haven't created your configuration file properly, which you are passing to `AuthenticationDetailsprovider`.
Basically, the following line of code parses the default profile from the config file added. You should not pass an empty object.

```
final ConfigFileReader.ConfigFile configFile = ConfigFileReader.parseDefault();
```

Comment: I already have a pre auhtenticated URL. I don't want to create it. Other than that there is some default info required in config file like tenant ID, userId etc. I don't have access to that.